# Enriched yoneda lemma proof

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, enriched-category-theory

This is an exercise in Riehl's Categorical Homotopy Theory. [Lemma 7.3.5](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/cathtpy.pdf)

> Give a small $V$-category $D$, and object $d \in D$, a $V$-functor $F:D \rightarrow V$, the canonical map is a $V$-natural isomorphism 
>   $$ Fd \cong V^{D}(D(d,-),F) $$

The author claims to show that this follows directly by proving they both represent the same object. I don't see this - how does this follow?

Comment: Riehl says that $Fd$ has the same universal property : take $x \to$ the enriched end (defined as an equalize); in particular it gives you $x\to \prod_e \underline V(\underline D(d,e),F(e))$, so you can compose with the projection onto $d$ to get $x\to \underline V(\underline D(d,d), F(d))$. Now you can use $I\to \underline D(d,d)$ and $x\to x\otimes I$ to get a map $x\to Fd$. You just then need to check that this map was unique etc etc. and construct a map of course from $Fd$ to the end, but this is canonical as well

Comment: I see, thanks, I will try figure this out now.